# How should one go about hosting a local test website in IIS8, and testing http bindings in browser?

Tags: windows, localhost, iis-8

Given the latest version of IIS at the time of writing is IIS8, how would one go about adding a new site through the IIS manager, set up HTTP bindings, and test the setup in a browser?

This configuration assumes that the named domain in the HTTP binding "does not exist" on the internet, but is simply a local moniker for testing (such as test.com and www.test.com.)

For a little background, I have followed the tutorial on pluralsight as well as I can for the IIS 7.5 version of this very task, but upon attempting to access test.com in my browser, I get a time out.  Localhost however does work.

Comment: If your objective is to test the site then what does it matter if you test it via localhost or test.com? You're testing the site, not DNS.

Comment: @joeqwerty - there are things that you need accurate DNS resolution to test on a website; for example redirecting to a canonical domain, or serving different content for different domains, or even I18N - en.example.com, br.example.com, es.example.com, etc

Comment: Mark - True. I considered that but as the OP didn't provide a lot of detail about the nature of the testing I didn't elaborate. As it is, if I want to test a web site I can certainly do that with localhost. If I need the kind of testing that you elaborated on then DNS resolution is certainly needed.

Comment: I think the key here was "Test the HTTP Bindings" that for some reason I only placed in the title, and not in the actual body of the question.

Answer (score 2):

We have no idea what the "tutorial on pluralsight" is, but the quickest and dirtiest way to achieve this is to edit your `hosts` file.

On any modern version of Windows, this is at `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Add a new line to the end of the file that reads:

`127.0.0.1  example.com`

(where `example.com` is whatever you're trying to test).

You will probably need to run Notepad as Administrator to edit the file.

Comment: I actually did this very thing, 
127.0.0.1 test.com exists as a single line, space delimited, in my hosts file.